# Foreign key fields auto increments conflicts in magento 2 install schema

Tags: magento2, install-script, foreign-key

I just converted the Magento 1(created by Ultimate Module Creator) module Install script for the new magento 2 Install-Schema script, here I got some trouble.

The referencing fields also has the auto increment. Please look at the below code that should make some sense.

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('vendor_blog_blog_comment'))
        ->addColumn('comment_id', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, [
                'identity'  => true,
                'nullable'  => false,
                'primary'   => true,
            ], 'Blog Comment ID')
        ->addColumn('blog_id', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, [
                'identity'  => true,
                'nullable'  => false,
                'primary'   => true,
            ], 'Blog ID')
        ->addColumn('title', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, [
                'nullable'  => false,
            ], 'Comment Title')
        ->addColumn('comment', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', [
                'nullable'  => false,
            ], 'Comment')
        ->addColumn('status', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, [
                'nullable'  => false,
            ], 'Comment status')
        ->addColumn('customer_id', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, [
                'identity' => true, 
                'unsigned' => true, 
                'nullable' => false, 
                'primary' => true
            ], 'Customer id')
        ->addColumn('name', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, [
                'nullable'  => false,
            ], 'Customer name')
        ->addColumn('email', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, [
                'nullable'  => false,
            ], 'Customer email')
        ->addColumn('updated_at', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, [], 'Blog Comment Modification Time')
        ->addColumn('created_at', \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, [], 'Blog Comment Creation Time')
        ->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName(
                'vendor_blog_blog_comment',
                'blog_id',
                'vendor_blog_blog',
                'entity_id'
            ),
            'blog_id', $installer->getTable('vendor_blog_blog'), 'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE, \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
        ->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName(
                'vendor_blog_blog_comment',
                'customer_id',
                'customer_entity',
                'entity_id'
            ),
            'customer_id', $installer->getTable('customer_entity'), 'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_SET_NULL, \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE);
```

I just need a way to sort out. If I am wrong somewhere please figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your action for the 'customer_id' field is ACTION_SET_NULL but that field was defined as not nullable in your script: 'nullable' => false

Try changing 'nullable' => false to 'nullable' => true

Answer (score 0):

`addForeignKey`, [accepts 5 params](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php#L412),

```
* @param string $fkName        the foreign key name
* @param string $column        the foreign key column name
* @param string $refTable      the reference table name
* @param string $refColumn     the reference table column name
* @param string $onDelete      the action on delete row
```

You have 6. Please modify to

```
->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(
            'vendor_blog_blog_comment',
            'blog_id',
            'vendor_blog_blog',
            'entity_id'
        ),
        'blog_id', $installer->getTable('vendor_blog_blog'), 'entity_id',
        \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(
            'vendor_blog_blog_comment',
            'customer_id',
            'customer_entity',
            'entity_id'
        ),
        'customer_id', $installer->getTable('customer_entity'), 'entity_id',
        \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_SET_NULL);
```

You had `\Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE` twice in the first Foreign key and `\Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE, \Magento\Framework\Db\Ddl\Table::ACTION_SET_NULL` in the second.

Comment: Param was not an issue in my case because for previous table I had the same parameter and it does works. it seems the Reference column Auto increment was the problem,m please look over "blog_id" and "customer_id" column both were the foreign key Column from Blog table and customer table which should seems to have exactly the same type and configuration as main table column.